# How To Set Min API To Certain Receiver/Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-widget, android-4.2-jelly-bean, receiver

I've created a widget for my application and I am using `TextClock` to display the time. Problem is, it isn't supported by android API versions lower than Jellybean.

My question is, how can I set a receiver to minimum API 17 in the manifest or something so the widget is not listed to those under API 17?

Answer (score 1):

Set the android enabled flag for the widget receiver like below

```
android:enabled="@bool/widget_enabled"
```

And set the bool value for widget_enabled in values-r16 and values-r17 to true and false in default values